# Fixed element inside Iscroll

Tags: html, css, iscroll

I have a page which is a big Iscroll. I am not able to fix an element with position: fixed if it is inside the Iscroll. I guess this has something to do with the transition Iscroll is imposing. Has any one faced this?

I would like to fix the "FIXTHIS" element. But unfortunately it scrolls along with the content.

JS FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/10amw389/1/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="scroller">
    <div class="fixthis">FIX THIS</div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#scroller li:nth-child(10)'))">Scroll to element 10</a></li>
        <li>Pretty row 2</li>
        <li>Pretty row 3</li>
        <li>Pretty row 4</li>
        <li>Pretty row 5</li>
        <li>Pretty row 6</li>
        <li>Pretty row 7</li>
        <li>Pretty row 8</li>
        <li>Pretty row 9</li>
        <li><a href="javascript:myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#scroller li:nth-child(25)'), null, null, true)">Center element 25 to screen</a></li>
        <li>Pretty row 11</li>
        <li>Pretty row 12</li>
        <li>Pretty row 13</li>
        <li>Pretty row 14</li>
        <li>Pretty row 15</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myScroll;

function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { mouseWheel: true, click: true,     HWCompositing: false});
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

loaded();
```

CSS

```
.fixthis {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #009BFF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  -ms-touch-action: none;
}

body,ul,li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: ubuntu, helvetica, arial;
  overflow: hidden; /* this is important to prevent the whole page to bounce */
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 45px;
  bottom: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroller {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  -o-text-size-adjust: none;
  text-size-adjust: none;
}

#scroller ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

#scroller li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: Just a quick question. If you want it fixed like a header then why can't you put it outside, just on top, of the `scroller` div?

Comment: I am also looking for the same, Actually inside translated div position fixed didn't work.

Comment: Your 'loaded' function setting inline CSS on "scroller" element something like that "transform: translate(0px, -200px)", this is the main cause creating this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please move the fixthis to right after scroller div ends and set z-index to something higher than what you want it over.